# What does the following code means? Why here is used "id"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1]; //why id is used here?

[tableView registerClass:[BIDNameAndColorCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
```

This is a piece of code from the book "Beginning iOS 6 development", chapter 8, p.245.

I would like to know why here "id" is necessary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385693/difference-between-casting-to-id-than-real-class-type-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` shouldn't be there. It should be:

```
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

The part in parentheses is called a "cast". This is needed because the `viewWithTag:` method returns a `UIView` reference but you wish to assign it to a `UITableView` variable. The cast tells the compiler that you know better and the returned view really is a table view. Without the cast the compiler will complain about an invalid assignment.

Using `id` also works here because `id` is a general type that can represent any object type.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not necessary here, and I don't think it is a good idea. `viewWithTag:` returns a UIView object, but the code needs to know about the UITableView methods.

By casting to id (which is a pointer to any Objective-C object), the compiler allows any method to be sent to the tableView. This could cause problems though, if you try to send it a message that the UITableView doesn't know about.

It would be better to cast it to a UITableView object instead. This would be `(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];`